# Finding height of floating iceblock above seawater

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, density

This may be a very simple question but somehow I can't seems to solve it. For the sake of completness, I will use the same original question I am working on.

**Question:** The density of ice is $917 kg/m^3 $ and the density of seawater is $1020 kg/m^3$. If a piece of ice with dimensions $ 1m $ x $1m $ x $0.65m $ is left in seawater, what height of the ice will be above sea water?

[image]

This is all it was given.

**My Attempt:** This is how I understand this problem.

There will be two forces acting on this ice block

- The upthrust force ( which is equivalent to the weight of the seawater being displaced)
- The weight of the ice block itself

Since the ice block is floating, I assume that the upthrust is either equal or greater than the weight of the ice block.

This is the simple sketch I come up with

[image]

but now I am confused because according to my sketch:

$ upthrust = \rho_{seawater} vg $ (v being the volume of water being displaced by the ice block)

$ weight\,of\, ice\, block = mg = \rho_{ice} vg$

If i subtract these two equations, the volumes will cancel out each other so there will be no height information left. I supposed I have to somehow retrieve the `height` inforation from `volume` using $v = Ah$ but I am not sure how. How do I find the height of ice block above sea water?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put net force to zero.  I think that the problem is that you use the same volume for the two formulas. In one you have the entire volume, in the other only the volume in the water.

Comment: Nice catch! In my mind I was always thinking that the two volumes were the same. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I hope you understand why the two volumes are different, gravity is working on the entire ice block. But archimede's law only on the volume in the water.

Comment: Yes, the volume of water being displaced is not the same as the volume of the the whole block as it is floating.